# SwiftLint causing build failed

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I am using swiftlint in Build phase - Run script. Build is failed because of swiftlint error. How can I proceed successful build but still want to produce swiftlint comments (i.e. errors, warnings) in my project?

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain why do you have a line of code that is 1422 characters long? If it's some text data (e.g. json), you should put it to a file and load it.

Comment: You have bigger problems than linting if you have a single line that is 1400 characters in length. Make that line shorter.

Comment: To really answer you question, you can either change your linting rules from error to warning in config, or you can process the output of `swiftlint` using some tool (e.g. `sed`) and convert `error: ` to `warning: ` automatically.

Comment: @Sulthan I know its a true violation, but currently I am building a legacy code and no time for refactoring but yet I want to know all the errors and warnings.

Comment: Isn't the real question here why the same rule generates both a warning for one line and then an error for another line? This isn't something that can be configured as far as I understand it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It can be your question but not mine for the time being, I want to know how to make build successful even after reporting warnings and errors. If you cant help at least don't put a downvote without reason.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That can be configured easily. There is a warning limit and an error limit.

Comment: @Sulthan, Thanks. Now I found it in the documentation as well. I guess the easy solution then for OP is to raise the error limit.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am sorry for my mistake. I don't know why people downvote without mentioning the reason. Please forgive for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either:

1. Change your config and remove the `error` limits, keeping only the `warning` limits:

   ```
   line_length:
     - 120 # warning limit
     - 200 # error limit
   ```

   vs

   ```
   line_length: 120 # warning limit
   ```
2. Change your build phases script to automatically convert errors to warnings, e.g.:

   ```
   swiftlint lint --quiet $@ | sed 's/error: /warning: /g'
   ```

You cannot have an error and still the build. Also I suppose that you don't have "treat errors as warnings" build setting turned on.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can modify the rules of swiftlint with your own custom .swiftlint.yml in your project to make the error into a warning or completely ignore it [swiftlint custom rules](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#defining-custom-rules).
2. Or you disable the rule for this one time with `// swiftlint:disable:next line_length` above your 1422 char line.

Comment: Can I add disable rules as command line argument? i.e. `swiflint -disable comma`

Answer (score 1):

Write this line above your error line.

```
// swiftlint:disable type_name
```

type_name will be your error name, in this case it will be

```
// swiftlint:disable line_length
```

Comment: That wont be feasible for too many changes and it also make the code dirty.

Comment: If you don't want to do this then you should make file name .swiftlint.yml and update line_length in it.